# Using multiple file suppliers in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

I have an application with `file-supplier` Srping Cloud module included. My workflow is like *track file creating/modifying in particular directory->push events to Kafka topic if there are such events*. `FileSupplierConfiguration` is used to configure this file supplier. But now I have to track one more directory and push events to another relevant Kafka topic. So, there is an issue, because there is no possibility to include multiple `FileSupplierConfiguration` in project for configuration another file supplier. I remember that one of the main principles of microservices for which spring-cloud-stream was designed for is *you do one thing and do it well without affecting others*, but it still the same microservice with same tracking/pushing functionality but for another directory and topic. Is there any possibility to add one more file supplier with relevant configuration with `file-supplier` module? Or is the best solution for this issue to run one more application instance with another configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the best way is to have another instance of this application, but with its own specific configuration properties. This is really how these functions have been designed: microservice based on the convention on configuration. What you are asking really contradicts with Spring Boot expectations. Imaging you'd need to connect to several data bases. So, you only can have a single `JdbcTemplate` auto-configured. The rest is only possible manually. But better to have the same code base which relies on the auto-configuration and may apply different props.